# How to deal with MS document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI library to deal with docx, pptx, xlsx and so on. It is strange that MS turn all the embedded files such as .wma, .vsd into .bin. Is there any way to extract them back to the original file with **proper extension rather than .bin**?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197300/apache-poi-xssf-adding-movie-to-the-slide/16322340#16322340). You can guess the extension from the mime-type of the PackagePart.

Comment: Yes this is good point. but, poi allow to embedded files into any ms document not for extracting...

Comment: I don't understand. Did you mean, this example/post is about embedding and you want to know about extracting? If it is so, do you need an example of how to get the PackagePart?

Comment: I know how to get these PackagePart object, but I want output all the embedded objects to independent files with proper extension. For example, if a audio file example.mp3 has been embedded inside a docx file, I want extract this excel file and output this to a example.mp3 file not a example.bin file.