# How to get AnimationInfo from Apache POI Presentation

Tags: java, apache-poi

There is a class called `AnimationInfo` which supposed to give animation information from Presentation. But my bad luck I could not get it.

```
List<XSLFShape> shapes = slide.getShapes();
for (XSLFShape shape: shapes) {
  //Need to get animation of this shape here
}
```

Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks.

PS: I am using `3.17` version of POI.

Comment: AnimationInfo is from HSLF, not XSLF - you can access the transition informations via *.getXmlObject(). Which information do you like to gather? Have a look at an [older example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197300/apache-poi-xslf-adding-movie-to-the-slide/16322340#16322340) for setting the timing information.

Comment: @kiwiwings which object has getXmlObject() method in HSLF ? I have tried HSLF too, I know it only supports PPT extension and XSLF supports PPTX extension. I just want to detect if there is any animation applied in the presentation or not in bot .ppt and .pptx files. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Only XSLF is XML-based and so only XSLF has a getXmlObject() method. I'll try to put some animation detection code together ... basically I'll use AnimationInfo in HSLF and look for timing info in XSLF ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the addition of only detecting an animation, a sheet can be checked for a timing information which quite likely identifies the existence of an animation, i.e. you could get a false positive in case an animation was added and then removed again. Furthermore you need to check all slides, until an animation is found.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.RecordContainer;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.RecordTypes;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlide;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShowFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

public class AnimCheck {
    private static final int timingRecordPath[] = {
        RecordTypes.ProgTags.typeID,
        RecordTypes.ProgBinaryTag.typeID,
        RecordTypes.BinaryTagData.typeID,
        0xf144
    };


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SlideShow<?,?> ppt = SlideShowFactory.create(new FileInputStream("no_anim.pptx"));
        Slide<?,?> slide = ppt.getSlides().get(0);
        boolean hasTiming;
        if (slide instanceof XSLFSlide) {
            XSLFSlide xsld = (XSLFSlide)slide;
            hasTiming = xsld.getXmlObject().isSetTiming();
        } else {
            HSLFSlide hsld = (HSLFSlide)slide;
            Record lastRecord = hsld.getSheetContainer();
            boolean found = true;
            for (int ri : timingRecordPath) {
                lastRecord = ((RecordContainer)lastRecord).findFirstOfType(ri);
                if (lastRecord == null) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            hasTiming = found;
        }
        ppt.close();
        System.out.println(hasTiming);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(Ljava/io/InputStream;I)[B` do I need to add any extra jar ?

Comment: .pptx extension seems working but .ppt extension got above error. Can we fix this error ?

Comment: Oh it's due to old jars in class path. Can we detect animation/effect in Shape object too ? There should the case that there is no animation in slide level but there could be effects on Shapes. Can we detect that too ?

Comment: I've create a few sample files  - w/o animation only on a shape - to test my code. If you get the wrong result with the above code, please send me your affected file to kiwiwings at apache.org

Comment: Your code is working fine for slide object. I want to detect on shape object too. I have sent you email. Thank you.