# How to create pptx file for Link-Video in Slide using Apache-POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to create pptx file having linked-Video in slides using Apache-poi.

I got one example in Apache-Examples code

poi-4.1.2\src\scratchpad\testcases\org\apache\poi\hslf\model\TestMovieShape.

Using this example I can able to create .ppt file but it's not creating .pptx file.

Also using this example media-controls are not visible.

Comment: I haven't validated if this is still working, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322340/2066598

Comment: The mentioned example is for Embedded-Video presentation. But my requirement is  to create Linked-Video presentation.

Comment: I would create a linked video manually via Powerpoint. Unzip the .pptx, as this is a .zip file. Check the slide1.xml (assuming the example has just one slide) and recreate the xml structure under the shape entry. With the linked answer you know how to manipulate the xml - so it's basically trial-and-error until you know how the slide xml needs to look like.

Comment: Previously I also think like this, I Unzip the PPT and I find in \ppt\slides folder slide1.xml file. But I have not found any link in this file by which I can use one as sample and create other by replacing the link of the media file. Not even I find media link in any of XML.

Comment: I does some changes in Embeded-Video presentation example.

Answer (score 0):

Only a few lines needed to be changed opposed to the [embedded video case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322340/2066598).
The video URI is not a real URI, but simply a relative .mp4 filename in the same directory. Although I haven't tested it, absolute file URIs should also work.

I haven't implemented the frame extraction, as it's mentioned in the embedded example - so either look for an archived version of xuggler or find a different library to extract the preview image.

Tested with Powerpoint 2016 / POI 5.0.0-Snapshot.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.TargetMode;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.PictureData;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureData;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.*;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipTypes.CORE_PROPERTIES_ECMA376_NS;

public class LinkVideoToPptx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow();

        String videoFileName = "file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4";
        XSLFSlide slide1 = pptx.createSlide();

        PackagePart pp = slide1.getPackagePart();
        URI mp4uri = new URI("./"+videoFileName);
        PackageRelationship prsEmbed1 = pp.addRelationship(mp4uri, TargetMode.EXTERNAL, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/media");
        PackageRelationship prsExec1 = pp.addRelationship(mp4uri, TargetMode.EXTERNAL, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/video");


        File previewJpg = new File("preview.jpg");
        XSLFPictureData snap = pptx.addPicture(previewJpg, PictureData.PictureType.JPEG);
        XSLFPictureShape pic1 = slide1.createPicture(snap);
        pic1.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 400));

        CTPicture xpic1 = (CTPicture)pic1.getXmlObject();
        CTHyperlink link1 = xpic1.getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().addNewHlinkClick();
        link1.setId("");
        link1.setAction("ppaction://media");


        CTApplicationNonVisualDrawingProps nvPr = xpic1.getNvPicPr().getNvPr();
        nvPr.addNewVideoFile().setLink(prsExec1.getId());
        CTExtension ext = nvPr.addNewExtLst().addNewExt();
        ext.setUri("{DAA4B4D4-6D71-4841-9C94-3DE7FCFB9230}");

        String p14Ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main";
        XmlCursor cur = ext.newCursor();
        cur.toEndToken();
        cur.beginElement(new QName(p14Ns, "media", "p14"));
        cur.insertNamespace("p14", p14Ns);
        cur.insertAttributeWithValue(new QName(CORE_PROPERTIES_ECMA376_NS, "link"), prsEmbed1.getId());
        cur.dispose();


        CTSlide xslide = slide1.getXmlObject();
        CTTimeNodeList ctnl;
        if (!xslide.isSetTiming()) {
            CTTLCommonTimeNodeData ctn = xslide.addNewTiming().addNewTnLst().addNewPar().addNewCTn();
            ctn.setDur(STTLTimeIndefinite.INDEFINITE);
            ctn.setRestart(STTLTimeNodeRestartType.NEVER);
            ctn.setNodeType(STTLTimeNodeType.TM_ROOT);
            ctnl = ctn.addNewChildTnLst();
        } else {
            ctnl = xslide.getTiming().getTnLst().getParArray(0).getCTn().getChildTnLst();
        }
        CTTLCommonMediaNodeData cmedia = ctnl.addNewVideo().addNewCMediaNode();
        cmedia.setVol(80000);
        CTTLCommonTimeNodeData ctn = cmedia.addNewCTn();
        ctn.setFill(STTLTimeNodeFillType.HOLD);
        ctn.setDisplay(false);
        ctn.addNewStCondLst().addNewCond().setDelay(STTLTimeIndefinite.INDEFINITE);
        cmedia.addNewTgtEl().addNewSpTgt().setSpid(""+pic1.getShapeId());


        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("mp4test-poi.pptx")) {
            pptx.write(fos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: kiwiwings Sorry For delayed response actually I have a hardware issue not able to test this. Today I worked on this and it's working very nice. Thanks for your help. I need to add template on this and I know very well how to add template. Thanks again.